# Vector-vector multiplication to create a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am an IDL user slowly switching to numpy/scipy, and there is an operation that I do extremely often in IDL but cannot manage to reproduce with numpy:

```
IDL> a = [2., 4]
IDL> b = [3., 5]
IDL> print,a # b
      6.00000      12.0000
      10.0000      20.0000
```

I'm not even sure of about the name of this operation. Maybe it is obvious how to do it in numpy, but I could not find a simple way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known as the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors. You could use [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2, 4])
b = np.array([3, 5])
c = np.outer(a, b)

print(c)
# [[ 6 10]
#  [12 20]]
```

Assuming that both of your inputs are numpy arrays (rather than Python lists etc.) you also could use the standard `*` operator with [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
# you could also replace np.newaxis with None for brevity (see below)
d = a[:, np.newaxis] * b[np.newaxis, :]
```

You could also use [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) in combination with broadcasting:

```
e = np.dot(a[:, None], b[None, :])
```

Another lesser-known option is to use the [`.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) method of the `np.multiply` ufunc:

```
f = np.multiply.outer(a, b)
```

Personally I would either use `np.outer` or `*` with broadcasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer!